# $\operatorname{Rad}(k)=\operatorname{Rad}(L)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Given a Lie Algebra $L$ on a field $F$, we define the *radical of $L$* $\operatorname{Rad}(L)$ as the largest solvable ideal of $L$.

We define the adjoint representation $\operatorname{ad}_L:L\to\mathfrak{gl}(L)$, from which we get the *killing form*: a bilinear symmetric form $k:L\times L\to F$ defined as $k(x,y):=\operatorname{Tr}(\operatorname{ad}_L(x)
\operatorname{ad}_L(y))$.

We next define the *radical of $k$* as $\operatorname{Rad}(k):=\{x\in L\;:\;k(x,L)=0\}$.

How can I prove that $\operatorname{Rad}(k)=\operatorname{Rad}(L)$?

Comment: Do you know Cartan's criterion (for solvability)?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not so confident with these tools, but now I look at this better, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true in general. Here is a counterexample. Let $L$ be the $2$-dimensional nonabelian Lie algebra with basis $(x,y)$ and Lie brackets $[x,y]=y$. Of course, ${\rm Rad}(L)=L$, because $L$ is solvable. However, the matrix of the Killing form $\kappa$ is given by
$$
\kappa = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
$$
so that ${\rm Rad}(\kappa)\neq L$; in fact, $\kappa(x,L)\neq 0$, because ${\rm tr} \, ad(x)^2=1$.
However, for a *semisimple* Lie algebra $L$ of characteristic zero we have, by definition, ${\rm Rad}(L)=0$. Since the Killing form of a semisimple Lie algebra is non-degenerated, we also have ${\rm Rad}(\kappa)=0$. So in this case we trivially have ${\rm Rad}(L)={\rm Rad}(\kappa)$.